# LAST_INSERT_ID() can't make this code work

Tags: php, mysql

I can't see what I did wrong, please help. I'm learning about Select `Last_Insert_Id` and I've been stuck for a few days now.

```
$result2 = $mysqli1->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    return $row;
}
$last_id = $row;

$sql = "UPDATE bao_admin_table SET Name='$name' WHERE ID = '$last_id' ";

if ( $mysqli1->query($sql)){

    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Registration successful!';
    header("location: success.php"); 

}else{
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Registration failed!';
    header("location: error2.php");
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: you can get the last_insert_id by doing like this $last_id = $conn->insert_id;

Comment: Before fetching the last inserted id I am supposing that, you might be inserting the records? right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the last_insert_id by doing like this

```
 $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
```

For more Info: https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp

Or You can do this way too

```
$selectquery="SELECT id FROM tableName ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($selectquery);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$last_id=$row['id'];
echo $last_id;
```

Comment: welcome..if it is useful for you  can you please upvote my answer

Answer (score 2):

I am supposing that you might be inserting recording, then only you can get last inserted ID.
There are 2 ways you can achieve it,

1. After inserting get last inserted value.
   This is how you can do it

   ```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
   if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) 
   {
   $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
   echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
   } 
   else 
   {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
   }
   ```
2. I am expecting that you are having atleast primary key to pull out unique records from table so, this is how you can get last id, by applying order by descending.

`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM MyGuests ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
}
} 
else 
{
echo "0 results";
}
```

`